# Help with conflicting mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to use foo on both of these mod re-writes this is what I currently have and is working fine:

```
#Links to categorys
    RewriteRule foo/(.*)/ foo.php?cat=$1
    RewriteRule foo/(.*) foo.php?cat=$1 

#Links to categorys with pagination    
    RewriteRule fooo/(.*)/(.*)/ foo.php?cat=$1&id=$2
    RewriteRule fooo/(.*)/(.*) foo.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

But really want to have this instead:

```
#Links to categorys
    RewriteRule foo/(.*)/ foo.php?cat=$1
    RewriteRule foo/(.*) foo.php?cat=$1

#Links to categorys with pagination    
    RewriteRule foo/(.*)/(.*)/ foo.php?cat=$1&id=$2
    RewriteRule foo/(.*)/(.*) foo.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

as both are relevent to each other (same pages) just a case of additional pagination id's but if I do not have the extra "o" it conflicts and so give me a 404

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that this rule:

```
RewriteRule foo/(.*)
```

...will match anything that would match your pagination rules, and will do it first. The simplest solution is to just invert the rule order and make a few small changes:

```
#Links to categorys with pagination
RewriteRule foo/([^/]*)/([^/]+)/? foo.php?cat=$1&id=$2

#Links to categorys
RewriteRule foo/([^/]*)/? foo.php?cat=$1
```

Additionally, if your script can handle `id` being passed with no value, you can just condense it all into a single rule:

```
# Links to categories with optional pagination
RewriteRule foo/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]+))?/? foo.php?cat=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: Thank you Tim the first 2 worked great :) ...sadly the second option "Links to categories with optional pagination" didnt but hey ho